# google apps domain verification issues

Tags: google, html, dns, google-workspace, site-verification

I apologize for asking this here instead of Google's forums, but I find that they tend to yield no results at all, ever.

I have a domain verified on Google Apps through HTML file upload, which I am currently using for email.

I don't recall exactly how I prompted the verifications, but I got prompted for one about a week ago for another address@mydomain.com, and I'm trying to find out how I can void the verifications through HTML, so I can switch to the newer method of creating a DNS record.

And finally, is there a way an individual can void unauthorized verifications through Google? For example if someone verified a domain you currently own at an earlier point in time? Google doesn't allow any support contact for normal Apps accounts.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**No Way of Turning Off Google Verification**

Google for various services such as Google APPs or Webmaster Tools will periodically check verification to check that you still own the domain.. There is no work around this, if you do not want interruption then you should ensure that you constantly have these verification in place for their checks.

**Domain Owners can use Hosting or TXT Records**

If you are the owner of the domain then it should be no problem adjusting the [DNS TXT Records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en-uk&hlrm=en&answer=2716800), If you operate a website on this domain then it may be simpler for you to verify your site as a on going solution using the [HTML method](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35658) which requires you to add a `.html` file to your hosting account. In order to use the HTML method you need to have FTP access or file manager access within your hosting control panel, You simply upload the file that Google gives you to the root path of your domain... I.e `yourdomain.com/google-verfication-xjkaj.html`.

**Verification is Automated as long as you...**

Have either the .html or the txt record solution in place then you will never get prompted for verification again.

Comment: So is there a way I can get the code to verify via DNS with the TXT record before I remove the .HTML files?